# Finding field with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web page in BeautifulSoup. I have managed to pull out the cells in the table like this:

```
 for row in soup.findAll("tr"):
     print "=========================================="
     cells = row.findAll("td")
     if len(cells) > 0:
         print cells[1].contents[3]
```

The cell I want looks like this:

```
<div class="detName"> <a href="/path/filename" class="detLink" title="Details for filename">Filename</a>
</div>
```

I want to pull out the href="..." part to get "/path/filename" but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: You probably want `if len(cells) > 1:` there, because it can be `> 0` but still not big enough for `cells[1]` to be valid…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cell only has one thing in it, a `div` (or maybe a `div` and some tail text), so `contents[3]` is definitely not going to work.

What you probably wanted is:

```
if len(cells) > 1:
    a = cells[1].find('a')
    href = a['href']
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, the print out is for contents[3], the cell has more stuff I don't care about. The problem is that I don't know how to go deeper.

Comment: @user2928103 did you try the answer? It should work. If not, then you definitely should rephrase your question.

Comment: Yes, that works. The 'cells' contains two <a>, but it is the first one I want so this works.

Comment: @user2928103: In general, whenever possible, you want to "go deeper" in terms of structure—that is, `find(node_type)`, rather than `[3][2][4]`. Sometimes (especially with really old sites) that isn't possible, but try it first. (Also, for really ugly cases, you might want to consider using ElementTree or lxml with XPath instead of BeautifulSoup.)